# Creating Custom Module to add new link for customer my account navigation on left side in magento 1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, navigation

I Create a new custom module.
My requirement is to add new link after Address Book in Customer My Account.
when click on that new link a new page show on right as address book.

What I do I'll Explain here, 
Please let me know what is going wrong.. No Link is shown after doing all..

Step 1.
Create new file in **app/etc/modules** named **Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses.xml**  Having below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step 2.
**app/code/local/Customerserviceaddress/Serviceaddresses/etc** create new file named **config.xml** with below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <serviceaddresses>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses</module>
                    <frontName>serviceaddresses</frontName>
                </args>
            </serviceaddresses>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Step 3.

Create Controller File **app/code/local/Customerserviceaddress/Serviceaddress/controllers** named **IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Hello tuts World";
    }
    public function testAction()
    {
        echo "test action";
    }
}

?>
```

After all this I type **yoursite.com/index.php/serviceaddresses/index/index** in url to check is my module working or not..
**It is working**... 
.
.
**After this Creating Custom Module's Layout and Block Files :**

Step 4.  **app > code > local > Customerserviceaddress > serviceaddresses > etc > *config.xml*** and add the below line of code:

```
<frontend>
<layout>
        <updates>
            <serviceaddresses>
                <file>serviceaddresses.xml</file> <!-- Our layout file name-->
            </serviceaddresses>
        </updates>
</layout>
</frontend>
<global>
        <blocks>
            <serviceaddresses>
                <class>Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses_Block</class>
            </serviceaddresses>
        </blocks>
</global>
```

So the updated config.xml is look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version of module -->
        </Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <serviceaddresses>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses</module>
                    <frontName>serviceaddresses</frontName>
                </args>
            </serviceaddresses>
        </routers>
         <layout>
            <updates>
                <serviceaddresses>
                    <file>serviceaddresses.xml</file> <!-- Our layout file name-->
                </serviceaddresses>
            </updates>
         </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <serviceaddresses>
                <class>Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses_Block</class>
            </serviceaddresses>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Step 5.

**app > code > local > Customerserviceaddresses > Serviceaddresses > Block** and create the file **Serviceaddresses.php** that contains below lines of code :

```
<?php
class Customerserviceaddresses_Serviceaddresses_Block_Serviceaddresses extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function myfunction()
    {
        return "Hello new world";
    }
}
?>
```

Step 6.

**app > design > frontend > rwd > default > layout** and create the **serviceaddresses.xml** file which contains below lines of code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <serviceaddresses_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="serviceaddresses/serviceaddresses" name="serviceaddresses" template="serviceaddresses/serviceaddresses.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </serviceaddresses_index_index>
</layout>
```

Step 7.

**app > design > frontend > rwd > default > template > serviceaddresses** and create the **serviceaddresses.phtml** file.

```
<?php
    echo $this->myfunction();
?>
```

After doing template, layout and block files nothing change..
What can I do to see the changes, that why My function in block is not call.. How can see the new output on screen.

**Now The Code/Files I add to create New Link in Customer My Account Navigation**

Step 8. 
Code added in my module's **app/code/local/Customerserviceaddress/Serviceaddresses/etc/config.xml**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink">
                <name>customer_service_address</name>
                <path>serviceaddresses/controller</path>
                <label>Service Addresses</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

Updated Config.xml will look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <serviceaddresses>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses</module>
                    <frontName>serviceaddresses</frontName>
                </args>
            </serviceaddresses>
        </routers>
     <layout>
            <updates>
                <serviceaddresses>
                    <file>serviceaddresses.xml</file> <!-- Our layout file name-->
                </serviceaddresses>
            </updates>
         </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <serviceaddresses>
                <class>Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses_Block</class>
            </serviceaddresses>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>

<!--New Section for My Account New Link -->
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink">
                <name>customer_service_address</name>
                <path>serviceaddresses/controller</path>
                <label>Service Addresses</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

Step 9.
Create New file in **my custom module's controllers folder** named **ControllerController.php** having below code :

```
<?php
class Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses_ControllerController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{   
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
            $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
            return;
        endif;

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

Step 10.
create new file in **app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout** folder named **serviceaddresses.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <serviceaddresses_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="serviceaddresses/serviceaddresses" name="serviceaddresses" template="serviceaddresses/serviceaddresses.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </serviceaddresses_index_index>

 <serviceaddresses_controller_index> <!-- module here matches node directly beneath <routers> in config.xml -->
       <update handle="customer_account"/> <!-- include existing customer account layout -->
       <reference name="my.account.wrapper"> <!-- target parent block -->
           <block type="serviceaddresses/customaddress" name="customer_service_address" template="serviceaddresses/serviceaddresses.phtml"/>
           <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer.account.link.back" template="customer/account/link/back.phtml" /> <!-- add a back link -->
       </reference>
   </serviceaddresses_controller_index>

</layout>
```

Step 10.
Create New Controller file Named in controllers folder of my custom module **Customaddress.php** having below code :

```
<?php

class Customerserviceaddress_Serviceaddresses_Block_Customaddress extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        if ($customer->getId()):
            return $customer;
        endif;

        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Step 11.
Old template file of my custom module's template folder.
file named : **serviceaddresses.phtml**

```
<?php
    //echo $this->myfunction();
?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Service Addresses') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php if ($customer = $this->getCustomer()): ?>
    <div>Hello <?php echo $customer->getName(); ?></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div>No customer here</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After doing all this no new link shown in customer my account navigation.
Let me know what was wrong in this flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XML block should be in your extension's `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/serviceaddresses.xml` file, not `app/code/local/Customerserviceaddress/Serviceaddresses/etc/config.xml`.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink">
                <name>customer_service_address</name>
                <path>serviceaddresses/controller</path>
                <label>Service Addresses</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

Your `serviceaddresses.xml` file should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <serviceaddresses_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="serviceaddresses/serviceaddresses" name="serviceaddresses" template="serviceaddresses/serviceaddresses.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </serviceaddresses_index_index>
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink">
                <name>customer_service_address</name>
                <path>serviceaddresses/controller</path>
                <label>Service Addresses</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

**P.S.** I recommend creating a child theme of RWD instead of modifying it directly.

Comment: Yes this is working for me.. Can you please let me know what is unnecessary code or files .. that not affect my account new link... so I can remove that. Thanks.

Comment: Everything looks good to me, my only recommendation is to move everything in `ControllerController` to `IndexController`.